# Download library using Libraries CDN

Tags: theming

Does anyone knows how to programmatically download a library from https://cdnjs.com using [Libraries CDN](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries_cdn) ?

Comment: Downloading libraries seems not to be the purpose of that module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@cilefen is correct: The purpose of the Libraries CDN API module is not downloading a library, but making the libraries found on a CDN available for your site; if then you are using the Libraries API module, it avoid the needs to download the libraries you need.

> Libraries CDN API is an API module to query CDN services to **automatically provides libraries** on your site.

> t also provides an integration with Libraries API. If your module depends on a library that needs to be downloaded and installed in sites/all/libraries and if this library is also hosted on a CDN, this module allows you to use the CDN version of the library very easily, **without the need to download** the library.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My bad ! 
Still, I am looking forward to download the libraries. Do you think there is a way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

While this is not the purpose of the [Libraries CDN API Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries_cdn), the module page does say that it's possible:

> Libraries CDN API is an API module to query CDN services to automatically provides libraries on your site.
>
> It is bundled with two CDN plugins: CDNJS and jsDelivr.
>   Check the very simple API to understand how to query a CDN and how to create your own CDN plugins too.
>
> It also provides an integration with Libraries API. If your module depends on a library that needs to be downloaded and installed in sites/all/libraries and if this library is also hosted on a CDN, this module allows you to use the CDN version of the library very easily, without the need to download the library.
>
> Basically, the module alter the libraries array and adds variants to it, these variants gets their files from the cloud, the module is also able to download a local copy of the library.

Basic API information and examples are available on the [module page](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries_cdn).